# For loop make it reusable javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some loop like this

```
for (let i = 0, l = this.documents.length; i < l; ++i) {
  if (item.text !== null) {
    if (this.documents[i].text === item.text) {
      this.documents[i].mandatory = !item.mandatory;
      break;
    }
  } else {
    if (this.documents[i].code === item.code) {
      this.documents[i].mandatory = !item.mandatory;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I have is that I have code smell, with so many if, else, can somebody help me to make it shorter and reusable?
Thanks

Comment: Hi, please priovide example input and output. Would be best if you could create small snippet.

Comment: Side note: `l = this.documents.length` is not a useful optimisation since about IE7 or 8. Browsers and engines should already implement this for you.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a schoolwork?

Answer (score 1):

I'd write it like this:

```
let doc  = (item.text !== null)
    ? this.documents.find(d => d.text === item.text)
    : this.documents.find(d => d.code === item.code)

 if (doc)
      doc.mandatory = !item.mandatory
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the key in advance.

Inside the loop, only a single `if` statement is required to check if a certain value match.

This approach takes the given loop because of unknown `this.documents`, which could be an array like object. Any other array method, like `find` needs an array and a conversion to it if not given.

```
const key = item.text !== null ? 'text' : 'code';

for (let i = 0, l = this.documents.length; i < l; ++i) {
    if (this.documents[i][key] === item[key]) {
        this.documents[i].mandatory = !item.mandatory;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @loop, sorry i do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one if/else for this

It seems all of those if/else branches are setting the same value. So you only need one if statement.

```js
for (let i = 0, l = this.documents.length; i < l; ++i) {
  if (!item.code && this.documents[i].text === item.text || item.code && this.documents[i].code === item.code) {
    this.documents[i].mandatory = !item.mandatory;
    break;
  }
}
```

Maybe a little more readable, but a very tiny bit slower in execution:

```js
for (let i = 0, l = this.documents.length; i < l; ++i) {
  var hasItemText = !item.code && this.documents[i].text === item.text;
  var hasItemCode = item.code && this.documents[i].code === item.code;

  if ( hasItemText || hasItemCode ) {
    this.documents[i].mandatory = !item.mandatory;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because we don't know what output you expect it's hard to help you.
But maybe like this?

```
const key = item.text ? "text" : "code";
const documentIndex = this.documents.findIndex((cur) => cur[key] === item[key]);
if(documentIndex > -1) this.documents[documentIndex].mandatory = !item.mandatory;
```

Comment: The expected output is mutation of the first matching document.

Comment: How should you know? You're not the author. The example code is clearly updating the documents array based of the unknown item.

Comment: No, the documents array itself stays intact. Only a single property of a single document in the array is updated.

Comment: Oh yeah, overread the break vor some reason. But in case the author wants an updated array, I edited my post.

Comment: Fails if no matching document is found.